# Way to use calendar format for numeric data input in Shiny?

Tags: r, input, datepicker, formatting, shiny

Is there a way to use the calendar input layout (ala `dateInput()`) for non-date data?

Specifically, I want to be able to open the calendar view but instead of dates, there be a grid of possible input values to select from.

The resulting graphic, if possible, would open like this:

[image: calendar inputDate selector]

(Note: the #'s are arbitrary and random in the above picture)

I've looked at the code for `dateInput`, but it wasn't immediately apparent how I would start converting the code in a way to use input values instead of dates...

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way with `fullcalendar` wrapper to `fullcalendar.js` which unfortunately still includes the dates, but maybe that is OK if you can get your data displayed as well.

```
library(fullcalendar)
my.vals <- c(112,87,45,66,10,6,19,412,8,99,100,74,12,106,
      51,58,91,199,14,22,80,18,3,39,2,1,17,596,4,1003,392)
palette <- colorRampPalette(colors=c("#ff0000", "#0000ff"))
cols <- palette(31)
seqtime <- gsub( "[[:alpha:]]+$", "",
        seq(strptime("2018-07-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"),
        strptime("2018-07-31", format="%Y-%m-%d"), 
        by="1440 mins")  )
data <- data.frame(title = my.vals,
             start = seqtime,
             end = seqtime,
             color = cols)
fullcalendar(data)
```

It produces this. The viewer defaults to current month rather than data month, so I had to go back with `<` on the display to get to July. I picked July because it had a Sunday start, just like your random data above.

[image]